# Combine every page's javascript into a single file, or serve page-specific files?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, http

Let's say I have a website with 26 different pages, A.html through Z.html, and each page uses different JavaScript files, A.js through Z.js.  I have two options, and I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions on which is better.

**Option 1**. In a build step, concatenate all 26 JS files into a single file, all.js, and include all.js on every page.

**Pros**:
- Once all.js is cached, it is cached for every page, not just the current page.  This reduces an HTTP request not just for subsequent views of the current page, but for views of every page on the site, even pages the user hasn't been to yet.

**Cons**:
- all.js will be, on average, 25x bigger than it needs to be, because it will contain a lot of JavaScript that never executes on any given page.
- Any change to A.js through Z.js means that all.js will have changed, meaning the cached version needs to be replaced.

**Option 2**. On each page, only load the file needed.  So on A.html, only include A.js, on B.html, only include B.js, etc.

**Pros**:
- Only load the js file that's needed, meaning the file will be as small as possible.
- A change to A.js will only affect users when they visit A.html.  B.html-Z.html will be untouched.

**Cons**:
- The user will have to load each js file separately.  So when they visit A.html, they'll only have A.js cached.  And then when they visit B.html, they'll need to download B.js, and so forth.

There are pros and cons to each approach, so I'm looking for help on figuring out which approach is superior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches seem ok to me but I would probably go with option 2 simply because the performance hit is smaller in the beginning and you only load what you need. This is like choosing between paying a debt with a 0% interest all at once or on several monthly payments. I would obviously pay month by month because I want to keep liquid as much time as I can (plus I want to get inflation working on my favor). In this case, if the user doesn't load certain pages you end up not paying that "debt". But I wouldn't go against bundling all in one file either, again, because the performance hit even though bigger, should be negligible unless you are building a monster app.

Whatever approach you take, consider bundling and minification of your files, not only JavaScript, but also CSS and images (use sprites whenever possible)

Comment: This answer is completely wrong, in most cases. It's much better to minimize HTTP requests. There is no performance hit to including a few bytes of extra JavaScript on each page.

Comment: @meagar did I say that there was no performance hit? Where? I think you should read my answer again.

Answer (score -2):

The accepted best practice for years now is to build all of your assets into the smallest number of files, and to minimize/compress the resulting files.

You should do this with your JavaScript, CSS, and images, in the form of sprites.

The benefit to minimizing HTTP requests **far** outweighs including a few extra kilobytes of JavaScript or CSS or image data included needlessly in each page.

Comment: You clearly didn't understand the question. In both scenarios the number of requests, at least due to Javascript resources is concerned will be exactly the same: 1. The difference will be on the actual payload size of the request. Even in the case of a HTTP 304, you still make an HTTP request.

Comment: @Icarus The number of HTTP requests is reduced by one for each subsequent page load. The single concatenated and minified script can be served from cache.

Comment: yes, can be served from cache but still an HTTP request with a header "If-Modified-Since" is made and an HTTP 304 is returned so the browser knows that it can load from cache. How else do you think cache works on a browser? Secondly, both scenarios explained in the question involve exactly one JavaScript file (read it again) regardless of whether is served from Cache or not, is the same thing, the difference is payload size, nothing more.